# DataGrid View Vb.Net - populating data

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagrid

I have the following code that I've been putting together to do exactly what I want. Basically i need to select data from SQL Server, get the count of the records, which I will display in a label (for now it's in msgbox) then i want to be able to populate the columns 0, 1 with the data from the data table. The reason why I'm specifying the columns is because I'm trying to make sure everything works since later on I'll be selecting a lot more columns but I will be hiding some of them (only will need their value). here's what my code looks like...

```
    Dim count As Int16
    Dim queryString As String = "select clientID, Dob, SSN from tblClients"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(queryString, Conn)
    Conn.Open()
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Try
        If reader.Read() Then
            While reader.Read
                count = count + 1
            End While
            MsgBox(count)
        Else
            MsgBox("No results were found for the criteria you've select, please update your selection and try again", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "No results found....")
        End If
    Finally
        reader.Close()
        exit sub

    End Try
    Using sdA As New SqlDataAdapter
        Using dtA As New DataTable()
            sdA.SelectCommand = cmd
            sdA.Fill(dtA)
            grdFind.AutoGenerateColumns = False
            grdFind.ColumnCount = 2

            grdFind.Columns(0).Name = "clientid"
            grdFind.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Clientid"
            grdFind.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "ClientID"

            grdFind.Columns(1).Name = "dob"
            grdFind.Columns(1).HeaderText = "dob"
            grdFind.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "dob"

            grdFind.DataSource = dtA(0)
        End Using
    End Using
```

I'm doing this on button click.....when I tried it before to load the data directly from the datatable it worked, but when I specify columns it doesnt. ANyone know why? Currently all I see in the Grid is just the Header Text. Is there anyway to make this a little more efficient?

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the data doesnt display?  You arent doing anything special with the columns (other than omitting a few), so why manually add them?  Also that first loop is not neeed: `count = sdA.Fill(dtA)` will tell you how many rows

Comment: @plutonix - yes i only see the header text for both columns. Well I guess i can hide some of them? Is that the correct way to go about this. Basically I will only select about 8 columns, and will most likely hide 2 of them. I will need to grab these values when user selects that particular row. I think creating them will allow me to name them properly so instead of DOB i'll have Date of Birth. See EDIT.

Comment: There are some dubious things there, but it does work with MySQL.  I'd be queasy about reusing the DbCommand object - since that reader loop is not needed, fix that.  If you AutoGenerate columns, you can change the HeaderText if you want, and hide some columns as desired.

Comment: Hiding columns has the advantage of keeping the data available to you.  For instance hiding the `Id` which is often meaningless to the user, but you may need it to know which one they Do Something with.  Also, **if** there is something elsewhere like filtering to show just those born in 1989 or whatever, you may want to hold onto that datatable

Comment: @Plutonix - i will need to have that ID so that when user selects it from the Grid, another form will display all the info related to that client but this info will be coming from multiple tables

Comment: Yes, that was the point.  You can hide stuff so you **do** have access to it without showing it.  The reverse is `SSN` which is omitted, so you wont know the related SSN without running a query to find it.  Above all, it was an example

Comment: @Plutonix so the issue was with this line grdFind.DataSource = dtA(0). I updated it to = dta and it works fine. got rid of (0)